# The logic behind the code that converts the byte into int in Java

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

Suppose a program receives an ID number of **4 bytes** from the source, and it will only receive 1-byte data each time. In order to receive the correct ID number, the developer wrote the below code:

```java
int IdLength =4;
int id = 0;
Byte databyte;
for (i=0; i<IdLength; i++ )
{
    databyte = ReadFilterInputPort();   //Imagine ReadFilterInputPort() will read 1 byte data each time 
    id = id | (databyte & 0xFF);       
    if (i != IdLength-1)                
    {                                   
        id = id << 8;                    
    }
    bytesread++;                        
}
```

I don't understand why we need the **bitwise or** between the **id** and the value (**databyte & 0xFF**). Also, why do we need to perform an 8-bit left shift operation on the id?

Comment: You need to show the declaration of `databyte`.

Comment: I suggest stepping through the code to see how the value of `id` changes.

Comment: I added the declaration of databyte

Comment: It doesn't have to be done that way, but it works. Imagine you have not seen this code, and you are given the assignment to create it. How would you do it?

Comment: If I were asked to do this, I'd read all bytes into an array and use ByteBuffer to get the value of the id

Comment: @Mr.nobody And ByteBuffer could do the same thing this code does (though in recent versions it seems to do something else), while this code avoids the allocation of an array and the allocation of a ByteBuffer.